# How is a Java operating systems possible?

Tags: java, operating-system

I heard about OSes written in Java, and the whole thing sounds like magic to me, specifically for one reason- direct memory access. Managing memory is very low level, and Java was consciously designed to hide exactly this kind of unsafe low level meddling. It doesn't even have pointers. So how do you implement something like memory management in Java? How do you handle context switches, which require you to access the system's registers? How do you do anything low level?

Comment: Can you give an example of an OS written in Java?  There are OSes written for Java.

Comment: @Thomas There's JavaOS, JX, and possibly others.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed. But yes you can write an OS in just about any language you just need hardware that understands the microcode/bytecode generated. The old http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_machine are an example of this. Java did have hardware support once... I think it was called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PicoJava.

Comment: Agree it shouldn't have been closed.  You can't write an entire OS in Java.  A so-called "Java OS" will require some amount of native code.  In the case of JX, for instance: "A small microkernel, written in C and assembler, contains the functionality that can not be provided at the Java level (system initialization after boot up, saving and restoring CPU state, low-level protection-domain management, and monitoring)."

Answer (score 1):

The kernel is not written in Java since it must support the JVM itself. Every other component of the OS can be written in Java. Even device drivers can be written in Java. JNode is an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Even JVMs running on top of Unix/Windows OSes have some C code to do low level operations. The code is hidden from the JVM's user and a lot of security restrictions control its execution. So I guess the OSes written in Java you heard of have some internal low level (C ?) code.

Comment: you can implement JVM in hardware.